# Jquery Mobile Alert HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, alert

I'm trying to open an alert type prompt when a link is clicked.

I have the following. Relevant code is near the bottom of the html.

```js
$(document).ready function jqmAlert(title, message) {
    // set up the 'alert' page..
    $("#alert-title").html(title); // Insert the title
    $("#alert-content").html(message); // Insert the dialog message
    $(".ui-dialog").dialog("close"); // Ensure dialog behaviour
    // Now open the page..
    $.mobile.changePage("#alert", "pop", false, false);
function testAlert() {
            jqmAlert("Hello", "A Hello Message");
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lab2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">.img {
        display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"
             width="150" height="120"/>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="#overview" data-transition="pop">Link to Module Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lectures" data-transition=slidedown>Link to list of lectures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#labs" data-transition=slideup>Link to list of labs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#functions" data-transition=fade>Link to a list of functions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="overview">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Link to Module Overview</h1>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h2>Welcome to Module Overview</h2>
            <p id="">Random paragraph of text. Look at the random paragraph of text. Wow.
                Random paragraph of text. Look at the random paragraph of text. Wow.
                Random paragraph of text. Look at the random paragraph of text. Wow.
                Random paragraph of text. Look at the random paragraph of text. Wow.
            </p>
            <p>Random paragraph of text. Look at the random paragraph of text. Wow.
                Random paragraph of text. Look at the random paragraph of text. Wow.
                Random paragraph of text. Look at the random paragraph of text. Wow.
                Random paragraph of text. Look at the random paragraph of text. Wow.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="lectures">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Link to list of lectures</h1>
                <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ol>
                    <li>Introduction</li>
                    <li>Web-App Development</li>
                    <li>Using RSS data feeds</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="page" id="labs">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Link to list of labs</h1>
                    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <ol>
                        <li>HTML 5</li>
                        <li>Web-App Development</li>
                        <li>Using jGFeed</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="page" id="functions">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Link to a list of functions</h1>
                    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=”#” id="testAlert">Test Alert</a></li>
                        <li>Web-App Development</li>
                        <li>Using jGFeed</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button onclick="testAlert()">Try it</button>

                </div>
                  </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>Page Two Footer</h4>
        </div>
<div data-role="dialog" id="alert">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3><div id="alert-title"></div></h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="alert-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the inline script and use the jQM pageinit method to bind the click events that launch the dialog:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=”#” id="testAlert">Test Alert</a>
    </li>
    <li>Web-App Development</li>
    <li>Using jGFeed</li>
</ul>
<button id="btnDialog">Try it</button>

$('#functions').on('pageinit', function (event) {
    $("#btnDialog, #testAlert").on("click", function (e) {
        testAlert();
    });
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/coc1ud1q/)**